# Why must virtual elements be public and can't be protected in C#?

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual, public, protected

I am new to C# and I am currently learning OOP. I am trying to learn how all these keywords work. I am learning the ***virtual*** keyword now and I made this class :

```
    // Animal class
    public class Animal
    {
        // Class propreties
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public double happiness { get; set; }

        public static int AnimalCounter = 0;

        // Class constructor
        public Animal(string name_ = "Spotty", int age_ = 4, double happiness_ = 3)
        {
            this.name = name_;
            this.age = age_;
            this.happiness = happiness_;
        } 

        // Virtual methods
        public virtual void Print() { }
        public virtual void Woof () { }
        public virtual void Meow () { }
    }
```

What I don't understand is why I can't write ***protected*** instead of public when I use ***virtual***.
For example at

```
public virtual void Print() {}
```

It gives me an error when I write

```
protected virtual void Print() {}
```

and as far as I know, protected means that the property can only be accessed in the base class and all the other classes that are made from the base class.

So I had a new class called : ***Dog*** that is made from the ***base*** class ***Animal***

```
// Dog class
    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        /* Class Propreties */
        protected double SpotCount_ { get; set; }
        protected double woof_happinessIncrease_ { get; set; }

        // SpotCount = > get and set // GET returns SpotCount // SET 20 if bigger or equal to 20 . SET 0 if less or equal to 0 . otherwise set it to the given value
        public double SpotCount
        {
            get
            {
                return SpotCount_;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value >= 20)
                {
                    SpotCount_ = 20;
                }
                else if(value <= 0)
                {
                    SpotCount_ = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    SpotCount_ = value;
                }
            }
        }
        // woof_happinessIncrease = > get and set // GET returns woof_happinessIncrease // SET 100 if bigger or equal to 100. SET 0 if less or equal to 0 . otherwise set it to the given value
        public double woof_happinessIncrease
        {
            get
            {
                return woof_happinessIncrease_;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value >= 100)
                {
                    woof_happinessIncrease_ = 100;
                }
                else if(value <= 0)
                {
                    woof_happinessIncrease_ = 0;    
                }
                else
                {
                    woof_happinessIncrease_ = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Class Constructor */
        public Dog(string name_ = "Spotty", int age_ = 4, double happiness_ = 3, double SpotCount_=3, double woof_happinessIncrease_=2) : base(name_, age_, happiness_)
        {
            this.SpotCount_ = SpotCount_;
            this.woof_happinessIncrease = woof_happinessIncrease_;
        }

        /* Class Override Methods */
        public override void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Name : {0}", this.name.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Age : {0}", this.age.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Happiness : {0}", this.happiness.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Spot count : {0}", this.SpotCount.ToString()));

            Animal.AnimalCounter++; // Increase the animal counter size by 1 every time we have a new instance of the class Dog.
        }
        public override void Woof()
        {
            // Woof and increase happiness
            this.happiness += woof_happinessIncrease;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} woofed. His happiness increased by {1}. His happiness now is : {2}", this.name.ToString(), this.woof_happinessIncrease.ToString(), this.happiness.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

I used ***override*** to override the methods that where ***virtual*** in the base class. But if I use ***protected*** in the base class for ***virtual*** methods it gives me an error.

Does anyone know why ?

***COMPILE ERROR*** : CS0507 : 
'function1' : cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'access' inherited member 'function2'

An attempt was made to change the access specification in a method override.

Comment: Q: Could you please update your post with the exact compile error?

Comment: You have to make the override protected too, it's telling you that you can't change the access modifier (public, protected, private). If `Print` is protected it can't be made public on a subclass

Comment: Because you're trying to change the contract defined by the base class. If the base class says something is public, it has to be public in derived classes.

Comment: You can do `protected virtual` but the base class has to have that field as `protected` as well.

Comment: If I change `Print()`, `Woof ()` and `Meow ()` to `protected virtual void` in the base class, and `protected override void` in the derived class, then your code compiles successfully.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/qvoqu6

Comment: Ah OK if you are trying to make the derived methods "more public" than the overridden base methods, then you can't just do that, see [Why can't we change access modifier while overriding methods in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6236909) . See [How to increase the access modifier of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/886977) for one possible workaround.

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful comments. I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issues with a public virtual method.

Make sure that the base method is `public virtual` AND that the extending classes (which override the method) mark it as `public virtual`.

```cs
public class Animal
{
    public virtual void Print() { }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public override void Print() { Console.WriteLine("Meow"); }
}
```

This is not supported:

```cs
public class Animal
{
    protected virtual void Print() { }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public override void Print() { Console.WriteLine("Meow"); } // Base is protected, so this doesn't make sense.
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer.

Comment: You can use the "new" keyword

Comment: The derived classes should use `override`, unless you want to hide the parent implementation in which case it should use `new`.

Comment: You can't use override to change the access level of the parent which is what he's trying to do..