# C# why we cannot define virtual protected members?

Tags: c#, .net, virtual, access-specifier

the code below causes the following compilation error:

> [the modifier virtual is not valid for this item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0106).

Why?

```
internal class Animal {
    protected virtual string prop; //<- error here: the modifier virtual is not valid for this item
}
```

On windows [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual#remarks) it implies protected is an allowed keyword (and i see no reason it wouldn't be).

The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328181/why-must-virtual-elements-be-public-and-cant-be-protected-in-c), but the answer said "the access specifier must match the parent class". In the above example there is no parent class.

I'm using C# 10 on .NET6

Comment: "The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived class. " You have non of that its just a field.

Comment: The SO question that you reference is not relevant to your issue. Your `prop` is not a property. It is a field. The actual error message is "The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this **item**". It is a CS0106 error. I'll submit an edit to your question.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because the question should not be editted to include an answer that was given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current code `prop` is not a [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), but a [**field**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields).
And fields cannot be [`virtual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual#remarks):

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a **method, property, indexer, or
> event declaration**.

*(emphasis is mine)*

To make it a property, you must supply `get` and `set` methods,
or specify to use their default version, like this:

```
internal class Animal
{
    protected virtual string prop { get; set; } 
}
```